# Prime number determination program

Tags: swift, primes

What's wrong with my logic? How can 9 come out of this loop both as a prime and not a prime number?

This works as expected for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 but gets hung up on 9...

---

```
var userInput = 9

if userInput == 0 {
    print("0 is not a prime number")
} else if userInput == 1 {
    print("1 is not a prime number")
} else if userInput == 2 {
    print("2 is a prime number")
} else {
    for var i = 2; i < userInput; i = i + 1 {
        if userInput % i == 0 {
            print("\(userInput) is not a prime number")
            break
        } else {
            print("\(userInput) is a prime number")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly responsive to your question, but keep in mind that you don't have to check any factors greater than `userInput / 3`.

Comment: @RomanSausarnes actually he doesn't need to check factors beyond the square root of `userInput`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This logic is flawed:

```
for var i = 2; i < userInput; i = i + 1 {
    if userInput % i == 0 {
        print("\(userInput) is not a prime number")
        break
    } else {
        print("\(userInput) is a prime number")
        break
    }
}
```

The `if-else` is wrong. Rather, you need to cycle through the *entire* `if` part of the for-loop *first*, testing whether each number is a factor (`if userInput % i == 0`), over and over; *then and only then*, if you have *finished* the loop and *still* have not discovered a factor, can you declare that this must be a prime.

However, you'll find it hard to succeed in writing that logic if you set everything up at a flat top level as you have done. The problem is that you have no way to do a true exit when you're at top level. Your logic thus requires that you put everything inside a function, from which you can do a forced early exit by saying `return`.

In this rewrite, I've done that, plus I've used a `switch` which is clearer (and Swiftier) than your `if...else if`:

```
func testForPrime(userInput:Int) {
    switch userInput {
    case 0: print("0 is not a prime number")
    case 1: print("1 is not a prime number")
    case 2: print("2 is a prime number")
    default:
        for i in 2..<userInput {
            if userInput % i == 0 {
                print("\(userInput) is not a prime number")
                return
            }
        }
        print("\(userInput) is a prime number")
    }
}
```

And here is how to test it:

```
for i in 0...20 {testForPrime(i)}
```

Output:

```
0 is not a prime number
1 is not a prime number
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 is not a prime number
5 is a prime number
6 is not a prime number
7 is a prime number
8 is not a prime number
9 is not a prime number
10 is not a prime number
11 is a prime number
12 is not a prime number
13 is a prime number
14 is not a prime number
15 is not a prime number
16 is not a prime number
17 is a prime number
18 is not a prime number
19 is a prime number
20 is not a prime number
```

(Also please note that I've used a Swift-style for-loop instead of your C-style for-loop. You should get used to the Swift style, because the C-style for-loop will be deleted from the language soon.)

Comment: Why would they remove the C-style for-loop? That would basically make code written in Swift before not work anymore if it used C-style looping. A language should always support older functions calls and syntax. That doesn't make any sense to remove it all together but to deprecate its use instead.

Comment: @DanielH There will be a warning at first, but eventually it will in fact be removed altogether. I don't like it either, but that's what's going to happen. I have code that I'm not even sure how to rewrite without the C-style for-loop. But I'll have to do so.

Comment: I’ve come up with another solution: the iteration can be done with a for loop or a while loop.  Otherwise, the solution is the same.  I’ve pasted them below:

var uI = 9

var isPrime = true

if uI == 0 || uI == 1 {

    isPrime = false

}

for var i = 2; i < uI; i++ {
    
    if uI % i == 0 {
        
        isPrime = false  
    }
}

if isPrime {

    print("\(uI) is prime!")

} else {

    print("\(uI) is not prime”)

}

Comment: var uI = 11

var isPrime = true

if uI == 0 || uI == 1 {

    isPrime = false

}

var i = 2

while i < uI {

    if uI % i == 0 {

        isPrime = false

    }
    i++

}

if isPrime {
    
    print("\(uI) is prime!”)

} else {
    
    print("\(uI) is not prime”)

}

Answer (score 5):

Remove one of the `break` statements. The loop needs to run completely until it finds a condition where it isn't a prime number. If it does not find said condition, it is a prime number.

```
var userInput = 9

if userInput == 0 {

    print("0 is not a prime number")

} else if userInput == 1 {

    print("1 is not a prime number")

} else if userInput == 2 {

    print("2 is a prime number")

} else {

    for var i = 2; i < userInput; i = i + 1 {

        if userInput % i == 0 {

            print("\(userInput) is not a prime number")
            break

        } else {

            print("\(userInput) is a prime number")
            // no break here

        }
    }
}
```

Or a bit more useful :

The logic is embedded in a function so you can use `return` for the control flow instead of `break`. Because there is a `return true` at the end you only have to look for `false` conditions. If it is not a prime you use `return false` to escape from the function and the `return true` at the end will never be called.

```
extension Int {

    func isPrimeNumber() -> Bool {

        switch self {
        case 0 : return false
        case 1 : return false
        default :
            for i in 2..<self {
                if (self % i) == 0 {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

userInput.isPrimeNumber()
```

The function is placed in an extension to `Int` so you can just call the function from `userInput`.

Comment: If you're improving his code, you might just as well use a `switch`-statement.

Answer (score 1):

My solutions look terrible in the comment box.  I've re-pasted them here.  Thank you again for all of your help!

---

```
var uI = 9

var isPrime = true

if uI == 0 || uI == 1 {

    isPrime = false

}

for var i = 2; i < uI; i++ {

    if uI % i == 0 {

        isPrime = false  
    }
}

if isPrime {

    print("\(uI) is prime!")

} else {

    print("\(uI) is not prime”)

}
```

---

```
var uI = 11

var isPrime = true

if uI == 0 || uI == 1 {

    isPrime = false

}

var i = 2

while i < uI {

    if uI % i == 0 {

        isPrime = false

    }
    i++

}

if isPrime {

    print("\(uI) is prime!”)

} else {

    print("\(uI) is not prime”)

}
```

---